# Delete line if next line starts with pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, command-line, text-formatting

I'd like to delete a line if it does not start with "a" "c" "t" or "g", and the next line starts with '>'. In the following example, "`>seq3" is deleted.

Input:

```
>seq1
actgatgac
>seq2
ctgacgtca
>seq3
>seq4
gtagctagt
>seq5
tgacatgca
```

Expected output:

```
>seq1
actgatgac
>seq2
ctgacgtca
>seq4
gtagctagt
>seq5
tgacatgca
```

I've tried with sed (`sed '/^>.*/{$!N;/^>.*/!P;D}'` and `sed '/^>/{$d;N;/^[aA;cC;gG;tT]/!D}'`) but got no success.

Comment: Note that the fasta format allows multi-line sequences. Just mentioning this so you can check and make 100% sure all of your sequences are one line only. Also, can't your sequences have ACTG as well as actg? And what about N? Or IUPAC ambiguity codes?

Comment: Sure, I know. That was just an example, sequences that I created to exemplify what I want. I have a file with thousands of sequences, and some lines had just the id with no sequences, and I just wanted to delete the lines with id but with no DNA sequence.

Comment: Fair enough. Many people come into bioinformatics and only know about NGS and short reads and are surprised to learn that you can have multi-line sequences in both fastq and fasta. Just wanted to be on the safe side :) By the way, you might also be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: yes, I am! Nice to know that there's a bioinfo stackexchange, I only knew biostars and seqanswers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$ sed -e '$!N;/^>.*\n>/D' -e 'P;D' file
>seq1
actgatgac
>seq2
ctgacgtca
>seq4
gtagctagt
>seq5
tgacatgca
```

That is

- maintain a two line buffer with `$!N` ... `P;D`
- look for a pattern that starts with `>` and has another `>` after the newline
- delete up to the newline

Answer (score 1):

An awk example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {lasta="XXX"} {if ($0 !~ /^ *>/) printf("%s\n%s\n",lasta,$0);   lasta=$0;}'  fileNAME.txt
```

equivalent to

```
cat fileNAME.txt | awk 'BEGIN {lasta="XXX"} {if ($0 !~ /^ *>/) printf("%s\n%s\n",lasta,$0);   lasta=$0;}'
```

Comment: Could you explain the syntax in this awk one-liner?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [`pcregrep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep) installed, you could try:

```
pcregrep -M  '^>.*\n[^>]' file
```

**Explanation**

- `-M` allows multiline matches
- Find a pattern that begins with `>` and ends with a newline NOT followed by `>`

Answer (score 0):

Tried with awk command working fine

```
awk '{a[++i]=$0}/^[actg]/{for(x=NR-1;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' file.txt
```

output

```
>seq1
actgatgac
>seq2
ctgacgtca
>seq4
gtagctagt
>seq5
tgacatgca
```