# Convert Multiline Database Logs to Single Line

Tags: text-processing

I have a Postgres Database log file and want to convert the multiline log into a single line.
The multiline log has a carriage return, line feed, and trailing line tab, which must be omitted.
According to my research, there are two possible ways to solve the problem, either on the basis of Timestamps or by using a Tab as a pivot. Each line without a timestamp has a Tab ASCII character in it. The tab is always at the start and at the same position which helps to understand that the logline is from the same block otherwise log block breaks if there is a new timestamp.

Here is my log file:

**Log File:**

```
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] LOG:  statement: select * from customersabc;

2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] ERROR:  relation "customersabc" does not exist at character 15

2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] STATEMENT:  select * from customersabc;

2022-11-03 16:58:26.796 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 16:58:56.674 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement

    ;

2022-11-03 17:01:47.331 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",

           pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",

           pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",

           d.datcollate as "Collate",

           d.datctype as "Ctype",

           pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"

    FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d

    ORDER BY 1;

2022-11-03 17:03:08.477 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",

           pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",

           pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",

           d.datcollate as "Collate",

           d.datctype as "Ctype",

           pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"

    FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d

    ORDER BY 1;

2022-11-03 17:03:29.546 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",

         pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",

           pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",

           d.datcollate as "Collate",

           d.datctype as "Ctype",

           pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"

    FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d

    ORDER BY 1;

2022-11-03 17:03:36.142 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clear" at character 1

2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] STATEMENT:  clear

    clear

    select

    ;
```

**Expected Solution :**

```
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] LOG:  statement: select * from customersabc;
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] ERROR:  relation "customersabc" does not exist at character 15
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] STATEMENT:  select * from customersabc;
2022-11-03 16:58:26.796 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;
2022-11-03 16:58:56.674 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;
2022-11-03 17:01:47.331 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate",d.datctype as "Ctype",pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;
2022-11-03 17:03:08.477 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate",d.datctype as "Ctype",pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;
2022-11-03 17:03:29.546 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate",d.datctype as "Ctype",pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;
2022-11-03 17:03:36.142 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;
2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clear" at character 1
2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] STATEMENT:  clear clear select;
```

I also tried the following [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586151/delete-line-if-next-line-starts-with-pattern)
**Code :**

```
sed -e '$!N;/^\t.*\n/D' -e 'P;D' db_logs.txt > output.txt
```

**It gave me the following output:**

```
22-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] LOG:  statement: select * from customersabc;

2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] ERROR:  relation "customersabc" does not exist at character 15

2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] STATEMENT:  select * from customersabc;

2022-11-03 16:58:26.796 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 16:58:56.674 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement

2022-11-03 17:01:47.331 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",

2022-11-03 17:03:08.477 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",

2022-11-03 17:03:29.546 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",

2022-11-03 17:03:36.142 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clear" at character 1

2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] STATEMENT:  clear

2022-11-03 17:08:01.281 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: select

2022-11-03 17:11:31.760 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 17:11:52.884 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: select
```

Unfortunately, it deleted the rest of the line.
I want a solution based on pure Linux tools. No external tools can be used therefore I used `awk` and `sed`.

Comment: Regarding `or by using a Tab as a pivot` - where are the tabs in your input?

Comment: Each line without a timestamp has a Tab ASCII character in it.

Comment: In it where - at the start, at the end, in the middle, all 3? If the tabs are only in 1 location, is that always the ONLY location where a tab appears?

Comment: Yes, the tab is always at the start and at the same position which helps to understand that the logline is from the same block otherwise log block breaks if there is  a new timestamp.

Comment: OK, that makes things simpler. Please [edit] your question to say that and I'll rework my answer. Do the blank lines within blocks also start with a tab?

Comment: Also - do you REALLY want a blank line between each data line in the output and, if so, why?

Comment: No, I don't need blank lines after each log line.

Comment: Then also [edit] your question to remove those from your expected output as they just make things a bit harder and raise questions.

Comment: Again - Do the blank lines within blocks also start with a tab?

Comment: I have to move on but I'll try to check back in later and if at that time you've answered that and updated the question I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '/^[^[:space:]]/{print sep; sep=RS} {sub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/," "); print} END{print sep}' file
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] LOG:  statement: select * from customersabc;
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] ERROR:  relation "customersabc" does not exist at character 15
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] STATEMENT:  select * from customersabc;
2022-11-03 16:58:26.796 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;
2022-11-03 16:58:56.674 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement ;
2022-11-03 17:01:47.331 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate", d.datctype as "Ctype", pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;
2022-11-03 17:03:08.477 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate", d.datctype as "Ctype", pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;
2022-11-03 17:03:29.546 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate", d.datctype as "Ctype", pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;
2022-11-03 17:03:36.142 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;
2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clear" at character 1
2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] STATEMENT:  clear clear select ;
```

or if you really want a blank line between data lines for some reason:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '/^[^[:space:]]/{print sep; sep=RS RS} {sub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/," "); print} END{print sep}' file
2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] LOG:  statement: select * from customersabc;

2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] ERROR:  relation "customersabc" does not exist at character 15

2022-11-03 16:15:54.330 PKT [3421] STATEMENT:  select * from customersabc;

2022-11-03 16:58:26.796 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 16:58:56.674 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement ;

2022-11-03 17:01:47.331 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate", d.datctype as "Ctype", pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;

2022-11-03 17:03:08.477 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate", d.datctype as "Ctype", pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;

2022-11-03 17:03:29.546 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name", pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner", pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding", d.datcollate as "Collate", d.datctype as "Ctype", pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges" FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d ORDER BY 1;

2022-11-03 17:03:36.142 PKT [5221] LOG:  statement: show log_statement;

2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "clear" at character 1

2022-11-03 17:07:30.703 PKT [5221] STATEMENT:  clear clear select ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I wonder why it's not working on my machine maybe I using ubuntu?

Comment: You're probably using a non-POSIX awk that doesn't support character classes like `[:space:]`. Try changing every `[:space:]` to `[ \t]` (but then get a modern awk, e.g. gawk, to avoid more problems in future).

Comment: @Obad, your `awk` on Ubuntu probably points to either `/usr/bin/nawk` or `/usr/bin/mawk`. Try using `gawk` instead of the redirected link of `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the following script.

```
awk -v ORS="" '                 
    /^\r?$/ {next}              
    f && !/^\t/ {print "\n"}     
    {
        sub(/\r$/, " ")          
        print                   
        if ($0 ~ /\r/) f = 0    
        else f = 1             
    }
    END {
        print "\n"              
    }
' db_logs.txt > output.txt 
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t+"; OFS="\t"} {$1=$1; print}' output.txt > out.txt
awk '{ gsub(/ /," "); print }' out.txt > oyt.txt 
awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' oyt.txt > new.txt
```